# how to execute sql query with count and store result in jstl?

Tags: jstl

```
select count(*) from tbl_products
```

I want to execute this query using JSTL and store result in variable. How can I do that?

Here is my jstl code

```
<sql:query var="p_count">
  select count(*) from products where prodType like 'Dresses'
</sql:query>
<c:set var ="cnt" value= ? />
```

How can I store this result in a JSTL variable?

Answer (score 2):

The [result](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html#bnalf) is stored in `p_count` (set using the `var` attribute). As you can see it is an object containing rows. You can probably find the count at row 0 and column 0

```
${p_count.rowsByIndex[0][0]}
```

Comment: I found better way to count and store result
`<sql:query var="p_count"> select * from products where prodType like 'Dresses'</sql:query> ${p_count.rowCount}`

Comment: That's not very efficient. Using `count` in SQL is faster and will take less memory.

Answer (score 0):

can use something like this

```
<sql:query var="results" dataSource="${snapshot}">
SELECT COUNT(field name) AS count FROM products where like 'Dresses'
</sql:query>
<c:forEach items="${results.rows}" var="result">
${result.count}
</c:forEach>
```